# filter only ip from the http error log using awk

Tags: linux, bash, apache, awk

i am using  below command in my bash script which filters failed ip from the log:

```
tail -1000 /var/log/secure | awk '/sshd/ && /Failed password for/ { if (/invalid user/) try[$13]++; else try[$11]++; }
```

this is working fine for the ssh logs under var/log/secure where ip address unique

i am trying the same for the http error log
but in http error log  the ip is combined with ip:port eg 1.1.1.1:44848
while running the below comman it

```
tail -1000 /var/log/httpd/error_log | awk '/denied/ && /client/ { if (/invalid user/) try[$12]++; else try[$10]++; }
```

try[$10] is the value for ip:port  but it outputs empty value.

here is the script i used to block ssh failed attempts
[[LINK]](https://striker24x7.blogspot.com/2011/07/automatic-blocking-hackers-ip-who.html)

and i am trying to achive similar for http error logs

[Mon Sep 27 00:20:20.195139 2021] [access_compat:error] [pid 17100] [client 192.241.208.127:38700] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/hudson
[Mon Sep 27 00:26:37.161248 2021] [access_compat:error] [pid 17097] [client 216.218.206.67:58598] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Also, if you could add full samples would be great.

Comment: You're asking us to help you write a script to parse a file but haven't shown us an example of the file you want to parse, nor the output you'd want to get from that file. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: i have edited by post ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub()` to strip off the port:

```
echo 1.1.1.1:44848 | awk 'gsub(/:.*/, "", $0)'
1.1.1.1
```